# Is my question for Math Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

In the first paragraph of [Prove or Disprove this Darboux-like sum of a function defined on infinite limit points converges to zero](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359027/prove-or-disprove-this-darboux-like-sum-of-a-function-defined-on-a-countable-se), I state that I do not know whether this is a research question. Is this worthy of research? Do you know how to solve this problem?

Is my question clear? Can you visualize how to compute my sums for a give $n$? Do you know how to calculate $n^{\prime}$?